# Grails Restful Client app, how best to structure OATH and views?

Tags: json, rest, grails, groovy, oauth

Yep, you've heard it before but I'm posting it anyway .. I'm New to Groovy and Grails. I'm trying to use best practices to create a Grails Restful Client App (eventually a liferay portlet) which will be able to pull JSON and render it in nice views.

I've found this great script which, with some modification at least pulls objects as JSON from our thirdparty CRM vendor, Awesome! So it's working but, if I'm not mistaken, wouldn't be best to modularize stuff like the OATH parts to a Grails service so it can be used in multiple controllers? I'd like to break the below (functioning) groovy script into the correct parts of the Grails app structure so I have an extensible app following best practices. Due to the version requirements of the portlet plugins, I have to stay with Grails 2.2.5. Any help chopping the code below up and getting into the right controllers, services and views would be greatly appreciated and help me (and others) understand how this works.

Here's the stuff I think might end up in a service

```
package school.infotech.edu

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.POST
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON


@Grapes(
  @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6')
)

def sf_login_domain = 'https://crm.thirdpartyvendor.com/'
def instance_domain
def access_token = ''
def consumer_key = 'BIGLONGKEYTHATWORKS'
def consumer_secret = 'SOMENUMBERSTHATWORK'
def auth_username = 'OURACCESSACCOUNTTHATWORKS'
def auth_password = 'WORKINGPASSWORD'
def auth_security_token = 'SECURITYTOKEN'



//Request Access_token and instance domain for work 
def http = new HTTPBuilder(sf_login_domain)
 def postBody = [
         grant_type: 'password',
         client_id: consumer_key,
         client_secret: consumer_secret,
         username: auth_username,
         password: auth_password+auth_security_token
         ]
try{ 

    http.post( path : 'services/oauth2/token',
          body : postBody,
          requestContentType: URLENC) { resp, json ->
                access_token = json.access_token
                instance_domain = json.instance_url +"/"
               }

}catch(HttpResponseException e){
    println "Error code: ${e.statusCode}"
    println "Post form: $postBody"
}


println "Access Token $access_token"
println "Instance domain $instance_domain \n"
```

So I think this stuff might be in a controller or a view but how do I invoke the service stuff?

```
println "List API Resources \n"
http = new HTTPBuilder(instance_domain)
http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
  uri.path = 'services/data/v28.0/' 
  headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"

   response.success = { resp, json  ->
     assert resp.status == 200
     json.each{ key,value ->
        println "$key : $value"
    }
  }

  response.failure = { resp, json ->
    println resp.status
    println json.errorCode
    println json.message
  }
}

println "List sobject Resources \n"
http.request(GET,JSON) { sobjectreq ->
  uri.path = 'services/data/v28.0/sobjects/' 
  headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"

  response.success = { resp, json  ->
    assert resp.status == 200


    json.each{ key,value ->
        println "$key : $value \n"
    }
      json.objectDescribe.each{ key,value ->
        println "$key : $value"
    }

  }


}

println "List chatter \n"
http.request(GET,JSON) { req ->
  uri.path = 'services/data/v28.0/chatter' 
  headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $access_token"

  response.success = { resp, json  ->
    assert resp.status == 200
    json.each{ key,value ->
        println "$key : $value"
        }
  }

  response.failure = { resp, json ->
    println resp.status
    println json.errorCode
    println json.message
  }
}
```

Outstanding questions are

1. Which chunk should go where?
2. How to reference from a service to a controller/
3. How to display the resulting JSON (as a map?) in a view?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The parts that make the REST call can go into a service that gets injected into a controller. Note I cannot recommend HTTPBuilder as it is a mess of dependencies, you’re better off with http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder or https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I like groovy-wslite. But no support for oauth. The maintainer suggests using httpbuilder for that :)